# How does "own" affect binding?

Tags: syntax, english, binding-theory

How does *own* affect binding relationships?

I am studying binding theory as it applies to English. I have learned that *own* can influence the binding relations. For example:

(1) **John** is **his** boss.

The bolded words cannot be coreferential in this sentence, but when one adds *own*, they necessarily become coreferential:

(2) **John** is **his own** boss.

My question now concerns the fact that the pattern is different when a content verb appears instead of copular *be*, e.g.

(3) **John** likes **his** boss.

The word *own* does not appear in this sentence, yet the bolded words can easily be coreferential. Why? How does binding theory account for this difference? It somehow relies on whether copular *be* or a content verb appears. But why would that be the case?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more to do with assumptions stemming from real-world knowledge than with syntactic binding rules.

"Being one's own boss" is a relatively unusual or paradoxical situation, or more precisely, a paradoxical description of a common situation: we normally assume that "boss" and "employee" are two different people, so that will inform our default reading of (1), and overriding that reading requires explicitly specifiying the opposite with "own". (Though arguably you could imagine a situation where (1) is read with the meaning of (2): *Q. Who's John's boss? A. **John** is his boss*. This seems marginal or humorous, but isn't impossible.)

On the other hand, liking one's boss is (I'm told) a common enough situation, so no such assumption informs our reading of (3), and *own* is not required to override it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!   I was wondering what real-world situation might occur in which "own" would not need to occur. Could you please give me an example for illustration ? Again, thank you for helping me with this question~

Comment: @Buffoon I'm not sure I understand the question -- isn't your (3) an example of such a real-world situation where *own* isn't necessary?

Comment: I think the phenomenon is a core aspect of the binding relations, contrary to the answer provided. There is no situation I can think of in which _John is his N_ would allow the coreferential reading. In other languages, the coreferential reading would require a distinct lexical item entirely. In Chinese, for instance, _his_ in (1) would correspond to _ta de_ and the coreferential reading would be impossible, but _his own_ in (2) would correspond to _ziji de_ and the coreferential reading would be forced.

Comment: @TKR Thank you for your response. I mean the situations in which _own_  needs not occur in copular _be_  sentences. ^ ^

Comment: @Buffoon It's admittedly hard to think of a good third-person example; I gave one in the answer (*Q. Who's John's boss? A. **John** is his boss*) which may not be acceptable to all speakers. With first and second persons though Google does find a lot of examples like *I am my best friend*, *You are your worst enemy*, etc.

Comment: The first and second person pronouns are distinct from third person pronouns in an important way. The reference of _I_, _me_, _my_, etc. is always absolutely clear; these words refer to the speaker/writer. The same applies to _you_, _your_, etc.; these words always refer to the listener/reader. The reference of third person pronouns, in contrast, can of course vary greatly. I therefore think that that the counterexamples involving first and second person pronouns are not convincing. Core binding relations are best probed using third person pronouns.

Comment: @TimOsborne I agree about the distinction, but that seems to support the idea that *own* functions to disambiguate or override a default reading. But I'd be interested in the binding account if you want to write an answer describing that.

Comment: Right. Critiquing the work of others is easy, whereas producing a better account oneself is much more difficult. I am hoping someone else steps in with an answer, someone who has studied binding theory more than me.